# How to hide menu settings at content creation for specific content types

Tags: 7, routes

I'm adding menu items programatically. Is it possible to get rid of this for specific content types?:

[image: menu settings]

In my situation it's just one more way to break something, and is totally not needed :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hook_form_alter` placed in a custom module or in your theme's `template.php` file for this. Try something like this:

```
function THEME_OR_MODULE_NAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // There's probably an easier way to check if it's an update or create form.
  if (!$form['nid']['#value'] && $form['type']['#value'] == 'page') {
    unset($form['menu']);
  }
}
```

I'm not completely sure about the `$form['type']['#value']` value. You might want to double check that so you won't get any false positives on other pages which also has forms. You could use `$form_id` for this, but that variable is unique for each content type.

Comment: This hook doesn't seem to work for this form. It fires when I try to modify search form, but does not when I'm adding content. BTW. by settings.php you meant template.php? :)

Comment: hook_form_alter fires for all forms made with [FAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7). You'll need to add some conditions so you only unset the array key for the intended form. If you try echoing something in the hook, does it print it on the node create/edit page? *Sorry, yes I meant settings.php, I'll change that.*

Comment: Breakpoints in my debugger inside hook_form_alter just doesn't work with this form. Printing also, it looks like this form cannot be edited that way.

Comment: This works for me with vanilla Drupal 7. Are you perhaps adding this to a template.php which isn't the one for your administration theme? Try adding it to a custom module.

Comment: You was right, I accomplished this with custom module. I learned that theme_form_alter doesn't work for admin forms, thanks!

Comment: Well, actually it does. But if you place it in a theme's `template.php` then it's only for that specific theme. And usually, you don't have the same theme for the regular site as you have for the admin interface. If you have *seven* as your admin theme, which also happens to be the default admin theme, then you would have to put that code in seven's `template.php` file. Glad it worked out for you!

Comment: Yeah, but modifying Sevens template.php is like hacking a core, I would prefer not to make changes to anything outside "sites" directory, so I think custom module is the best way to do this.

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely true. I was merely explaining why it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to hide this menu as well. However hampusn's solution does not work form me. The way I achive it is down there, in case someone does experience same problem.

```
$form['additional_settings']['#access'] = FALSE;
```

Placed in hook_form_alter as suggested by hampusn. Make sure to use "#access"

Comment: Make sure you're ok with hiding all of the fields that are included in the "additional settings" which could include Publish settings, revision, authoring, etc.